# How do we go about solving for two unknowns?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An equation `(x + 1902 * y) = 1.00238849294(x + 1897 * y)` has two unknowns `x` and `y`.

What's the best way to solve for two unknowns?

How do we get the actual numbers represented by `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a linear case, isolate $y$ on the LHS and $x$ on the RHS.

$x$ will be a free variable. In other words, you can make it whatever you want. If you had a second equation, things could change.

In this case, you end up with:

$$y = 0.00509242 x$$

Comment: Do you mean that there's no way to get the actual numbers?

Comment: Not from a single equation. You have two unknowns, but only a single equation. However, you are free to choose values of $x$ and get an infinite number of $y$ values. For example, choose $x=0$, so $y = 0$. You can verify that in your original equation. If you had two equations and two unknowns, you might be able to solve that and find the fixed values or maybe none or an infinite number too. Regards

Comment: Nice work! Needs another TU +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is "x" and "y" in terms of each other.

So if I had a function y = 2x

Then y is always twice as big as x, for every x ever.

Comment: This is the fun of algebra in many ways.

You'll love it once you get used to it.

If y = how much money you have.
and x = how much money I have.

And I always have 2 times the money you do.

Then x = 2y, or x/2 = y

So if I know you have 20 dollars... then I replace the y with a 20 and.

x = 2*20

or 

x = 40

I have 40 dollars.

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve for two unknowns
with only one equation
(unless there are unusual side conditions).

In your case,
since the equation is linear,
you can easily solve for $x$ in terms of $y$
or $y$ in terms of $x$.

In your case,
it looks like you are looking at
some historical data,
with two groups
five years apart.

Note that,
if you set
z = x + 1897 * y,
this becomes
(z + 5 * y) = 1.00238849294*z
or
5*y = 0.00238849294*z
or
y = 0.0004...*z.
I don't know if this helps,
but this is the kind of thing
I might do.